# Is it advisable to call my method in a Thread object while it executes another method?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

A thread consists of two methods namely **method A(always listen to the socket and read data from it)** and **method B(close socket connection)**.
Method B is a synchronised method. Is it a good way of programming to call method B while the thread is executing method A?

Main Program starts a thread(which contains method A and method B). once the thread become alive it calls method A repeatedly(in a while() loop). method B is called by main program when some conditions met. please take a look at the code sample below.

Code Example:
[image: This is my main program which starts a thread namely client inside connect method]

[image: This is the run method of the client thread which calls a method receiveMessage() which tries to read from socket stream]

While the thread is trying to read from socket if the user give disconnect command the main program should be able to call closeConnection method of the client thread.

Comment: It would be easier if you showed us.

Comment: Do you mean that method A calls method B?  Or do you mean that an entirely different thread calls method B (in which case it will run on the thread from which it is called)?

Comment: No . Method B is called by different thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes and no.  As it is with threads, it's all about the data since code is always thread-safe, (unless self-modifying - ugh!).  In your case, where the intent seems to be to shut down a client-handler thread by closing its socket from another thread, I would say it's fine. Same with, say, a method that queues a passed object to the thread by pushing it onto a private producer-consumer queue upon which the thread is waiting.

Such methods are specific to that thread, use no data outside the thread and it makes sense to keep them encapsualted within the thread, (or threaded subsystem), class.

If it was me, I would not have bothered with the synchronized null-set-check and just swallowed the 'invalid handle' error/exception that would result from those odd occasions when two threads try to close the same socket 'at the same time', but that's just me:)

In general, just look at the method, what it does, what data is touches, and make a decision.  It's difficult to come up with hard-and-fast rules in software because they so often have cases where they should be broken to improve functionality, encapsulation, ease of debugging etc.

Answer (score 2):

To me, it seems extremely confusing to have a method in one thread class which is designed to be called by other threads.  For the sake of keeping your code clean and comprehensible, don't do it.  Any methods that are to be shared by multiple threads should be in a separate class from the `Thread` class itself.

Comment: ..unless, say, the method is an inter-thread comms call, ie. it takes an object and pushes it onto a private queue upon which the thread is waiting.  That would actually reduce confusion and improve encapsulation.